# How to alter axis points on a simple stacked bar chart in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-365

Using Office 365, I created  the second type of stacked bar chart using the following data:

```
10.3 
4.133333
0.25
9.316667
```

The axis marks are automatically set from 0 to 30.
On changing the maximum axis point to 24, the minimum axis point changes to -1. Subsequently, on changing the minimum axis point to 0, The axis mark of 24 disappears on the chart.

I am trying to show the above data as constituting a whole of 24 hours. I had considered using a pie chart, but I would rather use a stacked bar graph as it represents the linear nature of time well (good visual representation).

If there is some other type of chart that can suits the purpose, I would gladly accept it. Otherwise, how can I tweak this specific bar chart so that the values are represented from 0 to 24.

[image: Link to the bar chart image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your major units for the axis are set to 5, so in the minimum value is 0, the axis will show 0, 5, 10, 15, 20 (25 will not show as you specified 24 as the maximum value).

If you the minimum and maximum to be 0 and 24, and you also want to see 24 on the axis, you will need the major units to be a factor of 24. For example, setting major units to 4 will show 0,4,8,12,16,20,24.

[image]